# String to interface conversion

Tags: go

```
str := fmt.Sprintf("%v", ruleSet)
```

Here ruleSet is of interface{} type actually contains a json collection . Which I have converted into a string .

Now I am trying get the it back in the interface{} format , from the string like this ,

```
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &ruleSet)
```

And I am getting the following error :

```
invalid character 'm' looking for beginning of value.
```

My actual intention is to store the string in cache in a byte format and retrieve it when ever required and convert it into original type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use marshal/unmarshal. fmt.Sprintf does not produce valid json:

```
data, err:=json.Marshal(ruleSet)
...
json.Unmarshal(data,&ruleSet)
```

Comment: Thanks Burak Serdar . I am feeling so stupid now.